# Flume can not found java (java: command not found, exec: java: not found)

Tags: java, apache, cloudera, flume, cloudera-cdh

```
]# /etc/init.d/flume-master start
Starting Flume master daemon (flume-master): starting master, logging to /var/log/flume/flume-flume-master-localhost.localdomain.log
/usr/lib/flume/bin/flume: line 193: java: command not found
/usr/lib/flume/bin/flume: line 271: exec: java not found
```

When i execute flume-master and flume-node, that message is appeared.
I just follow the menual in flume installation guide(http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/archives/cdh3/v3u6/CDH3-Installation-Guide/cdh3ig_topic_10.html)

I use jdk1.8.0_25 and set java on ~/.bashrc and /etc/profile.
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in `/etc/flume-ng/conf.empty/flume-env.sh`

> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

(JAVA_HOME according to your system)